# Searching a string for a match on a quoted phrase and other keywords

Tags: c#, .net, search

As an example of what I'm trying to accomplish, here is some code which builds out a list of books with a string property called `Sentence`.

```
public class Book {
    public string Sentence { get; set; }
}

Book book1 = new Book() { Sentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" };
Book book2 = new Book() { Sentence = "The quick brown frog jumps over the lazy sloth" };

List<Book> books = new List<Book>();

books.Add(book1);
books.Add(book2);
```

I want to search through the list of books based on some user input (the search requirements shouldn't get more complicated than this example).

If a user provides a search phrase of `quick fox "lazy dog"`, then I went to return a List which has book1 as a member of the collection.  If a user provides a search phrase of `quick fox sloth` nothing should be returned because those three words do not all appear in any of the properties.

**Summary**

1. `quick fox "lazy dog"` - 1 Result (the words in quotes appear together, and the remaining words appear individually)
2. `quick fox sloth` - No results
3. `"lazy sloth"` - 1 Result  (both words appear together in the string)
4. `lazy sloth` - 1 Result (both words appear individuals in the string)

The code that I currently have:

```
//Turn the search word into an array of words (includes support for quotes phrases).  E.g: quick fox "lazy dog" becomes a list of these values: `quick`, `fox`, `lazy dog`.
var searchWords = Regex.Matches(searchWord, @"(?<match>\w+)|\""(?<match>[\w\s]*)""")
                       .Cast<Match>()
                       .Select(m => m.Groups["match"].Value)
                       .ToList();

var query = from b in books
            where (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(b.Sentence) && searchWords.Any(b.Sentence.Contains))
            select b;
```

This doesn't work for case 2.  The code I have now is just looking for 1 match, and if it gets 1 match then it considers the item found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want the `All()` LINQ method, try this:

```
var query = from b in books
            where (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(b.Sentence) && searchWords.All(word => b.Sentence.Contains(word)))
            select b;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  You're exactly right that this is what I needed to solve my example.  I may look into Lucene.NET, but this answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reinventing the wheel I would use [Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/). You don't even need an index on disk. All index+search can be done in memory(using Lucene's RamDirectory)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I checked out their page, but I couldn't find any documentation on how to use it.  The getting started page has nothing of use.

Comment: @Ek0nomik [Lucene.net: your first application](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/09/02/lucene.net-your-first-application.aspx) + all Lucene.Java documents